# An issue accessing an AWS S3 object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an issue with getting an object from an AWS S3 bucket. It is at standard storage class. I can access and download it from the AWS console. But when I try to download it via `awscli` with the same user, it gives me an

> File is not found

error. I'm 100% sure that the paths of the files are correct.
Any ideas about this?

Comment: Please post the command you are using to access the file, you can obscure the bucket name and stuff.

Comment: In order to download using awscli you will need a Secret Key and Access Key. You will need to add by running 'aws configure' or add it to environment variables. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-welcome.html#cli-using-examples

Comment: Can you use `aws s3 ls` from the AWS CLI, to confirm it is talking with AWS? Also, it sounds like you are trying to _upload_ rather than _download_. Please show the command you are using to download the file.